# STOR command destroys connection with FTP server

Tags: c#, ftp

I am writing FTP client with C#. I typed methods to upload file to FTP server and file upload does work. However, after successful data transmission, client gets disconnected from server. Here are steps I do:
 1. Get IP and Port from server by using PASV.
 2. Create DATA connection with server using IP and port.
 3. Convert file to bytes and send through DATA connection.
 4. Send STOR through COMMAND connection

My question is why I get disconnected.

```
public void PrepareUpload() // Get IP and Port from server by using PASV.
        {
            String answer;
            String message = "PASV\r\n";
            Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            this.ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);      
            answer = Response(this.ns);
            this.dataPort = getPort(answer, 4) * 256 + getPort(answer, 5);
        }

public void DataConnect(string server) // Create DATA connection with server using IP and port.
        {
            int port = this.dataPort;
            this.dataConnection = new TcpClient();
            IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(server).AddressList[0];

            this.dataConnection.Connect(ipAddress, port);
            this.nds = dataConnection.GetStream();  
        }

public void DataTransfer(string filename) // Convert file to bytes and send through DATA connection.
        {
            byte[] data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
            this.filename = Path.GetFileName(filename);
            nds.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

public void Upload() // Send STOR through COMMAND connection
        {
            String message = "STOR " + this.filename + "\r\n";
            Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            this.ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
```

Comment: Do not post code as an image. Post it as text + Moreover your code does not show, how are the methods called + Explain, how do you detect the disconnection - What exactly happens? - Network capture or at least a server log would be useful too.

Comment: After successful upload, I try to use other functions I implemented: directory change, NLIST function, RETR function. I get no response from server side after successful file upload. If file upload fails or it is not even used other functions work well.

Comment: "No response" and "disconnect" are two different things. If you need our help, you need to be exact.  And provide the information, I've asked you for.

Comment: Why not use the included facilities on C# to connect to a FTP server? Check FtpWebRequest.

Comment: It is not allowed to use these libraries for our assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The order you describe is wrong. In particular you should not start data transfer before issuing the command which specifies what should happen with the transferred data (i.e. STOR). The correct order would be:

1. Use PASV or PORT command to determine data port and get response to this command. In case of PORT listen on the given IP:port.
2. **Send the STOR command** and read the response. It should be a preliminary response (150).
3. Create the data connection: with PASV connect to the remote host, with PORT wait for an incoming connections.
4. **Transfer the data** and close the data connection.
5. Wait for the final response (226).

Comment: I did change the order as it is in your example. The file is successfully uploaded on server. However, same problem as explained in post. I get no response in the second step. (!networkStream.DataAvailable). However step 5 I get "150 ok to send data"

Comment: @user7038346: I cannot see anything in your code which read the response from the server after sending the STOR. A quick check with a working FTP client and exactly this server shows that the order I gave is exactly the one which is working, i.e. first read the response to the STOR and then connect to the server with the data connection. And while I'm not familiar with .NET I don't think that you should check DataAvailable if the response is already there: since it only gets send by the server after getting the command you should wait for the response instead.